# Selenium Web Driver didnt return the page source that I am interested in

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to a website, which I believe is a dynamic website.
https://publicrecordsaccess.fultoncountyga.gov/Portal/Home/WorkspaceMode?p=0

If the link needs you to search again, here is what I put for the Search Criteria: 16ED* then click Advanced Filtering Options to choose the Filter by File Date Start: 01/01/2016 and Filter by File Date End: 01/08/2016. Then click submit. You will go to the webpage that I need to scrape from.

I used selenium chrome web driver to do this task, but every time when I put in the link, it will automatically show me the page that hasn't been put in any search criteria. So I pause the driver for 60 seconds in order to have enough time to navigate to the page that I need to scrape from. But for some reason, it still didn't scrape the page source that I need to scrape from.

I used the developer tools to inspect the source, rather than just view the page source. Since using Inspect is the only way to find the elements that I need to scrape from. I am wondering are there any ways to do this task or did I do something wrong with my code.

```
web = 'https://publicrecordsaccess.fultoncountyga.gov/Portal/Home/WorkspaceMode?p=0'
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get(web)
time.sleep(60)
plain_text = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
```

Update for the post/question.

The URL: https://publicrecordsaccess.fultoncountyga.gov/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29

I need to put in the information for the search criteria in order to go to the page that I am interested in.

Here is what I put for the Search Criteria:16ED* then click Advanced Filtering Options to choose the Filter by File Date Start: 01/01/2016 and Filter by File Date End: 01/08/2016. Then click submit. You will go to the webpage that I need to scrape from.

My goal is to scrape the website from Case Number, Style/Defendant, File Date, Type, Status, and the corresponding URL for the Case. Then store them into a data frame. I can see all the information when I used Developer Tools then click Inspect on Google Chrome. And since I know it is a dynamic website, I wrote code that uses Selenium to scrape the website.

Comment: enough time to navigate to the page - what are these steps ? `driver.page_source` won't give you dynamic content

Comment: @cruisepandey to have enough time to put in all the search criteria that I need. So I decided to pause it for 60 seconds

Comment: `sleep()` will put program thread to sleep, not driver. I would like to know `search criteria`

Comment: @cruisepandey Then how can I solve it, coz I need to put in the search criteria every time

Comment: If you tell me exactly what you are doing, probably I can assist you

Comment: @cruisepandey I just updated my post. Let me know whether it is clear or not. Thank you so much!

Comment: I will have a look, but I can't do this right now. Will update you in this same thread.

Comment: @cruisepandey No problem at all! If you want, we can communicate via chat or email.